# json_encode and parsing information if there are no records returned

Tags: php, ajax, json

I make some AJAX (PHP + JQuery), but I have one problem.
I have:
dataType:"json",

in Javascript

Everything works fine when json_encode returning some records from DB.
The problem is what to do, how to say server in case that there are not any records?

When I have an array which is encoded to JSON is ok.
WHen array is empty the json_enocde returning NULL.
But this is not in expected format so I can't catch this error.

Hope, question is clear :)

Comment: Why not just make a case that if a NULL value is returned, another action will take place? Meaning, why don't you just handle the case?

Comment: if(empty($response)) { echo json_encode(['error' => true']) }  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two (of several) possibilities:

PHP Option:

Handle the NULL object to make it parseble ahead of time...

```
if ($mydata==NULL) {
    $mydata = new stdClass();
}
echo json_decode($mydata);
```

JS Option:

Try catching the error when parsing it on the client side.

```
// Catch the error
try {
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
} catch(error) {
    // Handle the error
}
```